# If set $S$ is a spanning set in vector space $V$, then $V$ is also a subspace of $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asking this question to clarify some properties of a spanning set and subspaces. My textbook says the following:

> If set $S$ spans the vector space $V$, then it can be said that $S$ is the spanning set of $V$.

> If $S$ is a set of vectors in vector space $V$, then the span of $S$ is the set of all linear combination of the vectors of $S$ and is a subspace of the vector space.

My question is

1. if set $S$ spans the entire vector space $V$, then can the following also be inferred?

- set $S$ is a subspace of vector space $V$;
- vector space $V$ is a subspace of $S$.

2. My textbook claims that a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ itself. If S spans vector space $V$ and is a subspace of $V$, does this make $V$ equivalent or equal to set $S$ of vectors given that they are both vector spaces that can also be subspaces of each other??

Comment: $S$ need not be a vector space, in general, so you cannot conclude that $S$ is a subspace of $V$, or vice versa. What you can say is that $\langle S \rangle$, the subspace generated by $S$, is equal to $V$.

Comment: To take an example, let $S = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$. This set spans $\mathbb R^2$ but it is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, because it isn't a vector space. But we do have $\langle S \rangle = \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Why isn't the S considered a vector space? Which axioms does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't contain the zero vector $(0,0)$. It isn't closed under addition, e.g. it doesn't contain $(1,0) + (0,1) = (1,1)$. It isn't closed under scalar multiplication, e.g. it doesn't contain $2(1,0) = (2,0)$.

Comment: ahhh okay. That makes more sense. I am trying to visualize the set in my head....is (0,1) and (1,0) points on the 2d plane? How can you change the set to form a line on the 2d plane?

Answer (score 1):

No, $S$ does not need to be a vector space at all.  For example, in the vector space $V = \mathbb R^2$, $S$ might consist of just two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. For the simple reason that a spanning set is NOT (in general) a vector space, nor a subspace of a vector space.
2. Hence this question is meaningless.